# Image skew in javascript with Jimp module

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, skew, jimp

I'm trying to skew an uploaded image with [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp).

There is a plugin for 3D
https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/plugin-displace

But I'm having trouble understanding exactly how this module works. Despite my research, I could not find even an example usage.

```
   const imageJimp = await Jimp.read(https://picsum.photos/200);
   const imageJimp2 = await Jimp.read(https://picsum.photos/300);
   await imageJimp.displace(imageJimp2, 30)
```

What I want to do is to skew the image, just like in CSS...

Comment: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/plugin-rotate

Comment: This rotates feature. It's not skew or 2D.